# R error - Error in model.frame.default(formula = levels ~ pvi, data = schools) : object is not a matrix

Tags: r

So to start, I'm very new to Stack, this is my first question so apologies in advance if the formatting is off. I'm trying to run an ordered `logit` model (something else I'm very new to) and I keep getting an error message. I have a df 297 obs of 47 variables with some missing data. I'm trying to run

```
fit1 <- polr(levels ~ pvi, data = schools, Hess = TRUE)
```

but I keep getting the error message

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = levels ~ pvi, data = schools) : 
>     object is not a matrix

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this error.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the output of `dput(schools)` by editing the question?

Comment: The output is too long to paste on here

Comment: You can paste `dput(head(schools, 50))` first 50 rows of your dataset.

Comment: Even just doing ```dput(head(schools, 1))``` was too long.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the missing data. Change the `na.action = na.omit`in the polr function to omit the NAs. Otherwise remove them manually or impute with different values.

Comment: It didn't work. I've run lm() with the same df without an issue.